# Questions about rebirth

Tags: discussion

I wanted to apologise for starting so many of them. Maybe it came off like I was putting people down, or aggrandizing myself, by doing so. I believe in rebirth, but that doesn't make me special, only arguably right. I'm using stack exchange to help me find out if there are any communicable reasons to believe in it, and I hope that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Rebirth" was the first question I asked on this site:

- [Is rebirth a delusional belief?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3420/254)

And then I didn't ask that question again.

Answer (score -1):

'Rebirth' is a very loose English translation about resultant states of being that follow from kamma (action). For example, a person murders or steals and, as a result, end up in prison.

The purpose of believing in 'rebirth' is to encourage people to do good actions and discourage harmful actions.